# Prove that intersection of $M_2$ and $S^3$ is a manifold

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

I’m having difficulty solving this problem.
Could you tell me how to prove this?
I showed the intersection with two variables, but still don’t see how to prove that it’s a manifold.

↓the problem and what I did to solve this.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Klfds.jpg)

Comment: The link in your question seems to describe a different question than your title.  Could you please state the problem more carefully?  I think you are asking about how to show that $S^3 \cap Y_0$ is a smooth 2-manifold, where $Y_0$ is the set of singular $2 \times 2$ matrices identified with a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: That’s right!! Thank you for pointing out that!

Comment: Note that $Y_0$ is a smooth hypersurface away from the origin. Geometrically, it will be transverse to the unit sphere, and this answers your question. But you can also consider the mapping $F\colon\Bbb R^4\to\Bbb R^2$; $F(a,b,c,d) = (ad-bc, a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2-1)$ and show that $0$ is a regular value of $F$.

Comment: So, can I prove this by considering F (which you presented) and making sure that rankJF=2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this, using your method, would be to show that $M=Y_0\cap S^3$ is the image of an embedding. For this use the parametrization you calculated.

Here is a second way to solve this problem. Define

$$f:A\in\mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{R}) \longmapsto (Tr(A^{t}A),det(A))\in \mathbb{R}^2$$

Then $M=f^{-1}(\{(1,0)\})$ so you just have to show that $(1,0)$ is a regular value of $f$. To do so let $A\in f^{-1}(\{(1,0)\})$. Then

$$d_Af\cdot H = (2Tr(A^tH),Tr(Com(A)^tH))$$

So $Ker(d_Af) =Vect(A,Com(A))^{\bot}$ which has dimension 2. By the rank theorem, $d_Af$ is onto which means that $A$ is regular. So $(1,0)$ is a regular value for $f$.

(Here I use the scalar product $(A,B)\to Tr(A^tB)$)

**Edit:** It is not so obvious why $Vect(A,Com(A))^{\bot}$ has dimension 2, here is a complete proof. We show that $A$ and $Com(A)$ are linearly independent. Let $\lambda,\mu$ such that $$\lambda A+\mu Com(A)=0.$$
Then $$0=\lambda AA^t+\mu Com(A)A^t=\lambda AA^t+\mu det(A)I_2=\lambda AA^t,$$
so $0=Tr(\lambda AA^t)=\lambda Tr(AA^t)=\lambda$. But $A\not = 0$ so $Com(A)\not =0$ so $\mu Com(A) = 0 \Rightarrow \mu=0$, which end the proof.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me the methods! I’ll try to understand this!

Comment: I can try to do it with your method, can you provide the calculations that brought you to your final equation?

Comment: Thank you very much! That’s so kind of you! Please wait a while...

Comment: I’m very sorry!! I had to show that the intersection of S^3 and Y0 is a two dimensional differentiable manifold!

Comment: This is my calculations→(https://i.stack.imgur.com/A16Pg.jpg)